# C String concatenation using memcpy not appending

Tags: c, string, memcpy

In some network code I need to encode packet structures in a buffer to send(2) over a socket but memcpy'ing the encoded buffers into a bigger buffer seems problematic. 
Here's a small code example illustrating what I am doing:

```
char    tbuf[] = "test";
char    *buf = malloc(300);
memset(buf, '\0', 300);

int     bytes_to_copy = 300;
int     bytes_copied = 0;

while (bytes_copied < bytes_to_copy) {
    memcpy(buf + bytes_copied, tbuf, sizeof(tbuf));
    bytes_copied += sizeof(tbuf);
}
/* free, return */
```

This should append "test" 60 times into buf but buf ends up only containing one "test". Am I using memcpy wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are repeatedly copying the null terminator at the end of test. `sizeof tbuf` is 5.

So all the C standard library functions will ignore all the other concatenants.

The solution: copy one less byte in the `memcpy`, and be sure to add a null terminator to the final string.

Comment: memcpy(buf + bytes_copied, tbuf, sizeof(tbuf) - 1);

Comment: This should work since it doesn't include the nul terminator but still the same problem.

Comment: Don't forget the following line where you increment `bytes_copied`.

Comment: `memcpy(buf + bytes_copied, tbuf, sizeof(tbuf)-1);
    bytes_copied += sizeof(tbuf)-1;`